# The sum of n numbers that cube to one is congruent modulus three.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb C$ cube to give one. Assume $\sum a_i=\sum a_i^2$. How can we see that $\sum a_i\equiv n(mod3)$? May the sum be different than $n$?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what these $a_i$ are - e.g. integers,  complex cube roots of unity and about whether equality and congruence are the same or different. Do you mean $a_i^3=1$ or $a_i^3\equiv 1$?

Comment: The $a$'s are cube roots of unity, Mr. @Bennet. Equality is not the same as congruence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given conditions, we must have $a_{j}=\exp(2\pi i k/3)$ where $k=0,1,2$.
If the $a_{j}$ consist of $n_{k}$ elements with a particular value of $k$, then $a_{j}^{2}$ consists of $n_{0}$ $1$s, $n_{1}$ $e^{4\pi i/3}$s and $n_{2}$ $e^{2\pi i/3}$s.
Thus, $\sum a_{j}=\sum a_{j}^{2}$ implies that $n_{0}+n_{1} e^{2\pi i/3}+n_{2}e^{4\pi i/3}=n_{0}+n_{2}e^{2\pi i/3}+n_{1}e^{4\pi i /3}$. Thus, $(n_{1}-n_{2})e^{2\pi i/3}=(n_{1}-n_{2})e^{4\pi i/3}$, which tells us that $n_{1}=n_{2}$. Is that enough?

Comment: I'm sorry. The $a$'s are not integers. They are on the unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $a_i=1$ then it contributes $1$ to each of the sums. If we delete it, we do not change the condition, and $n$ reduces by $1$, so we do not change the validity of the congruence. We assume that none of the $a_i$ are equal to $1$.

We have $a_i^3-1=(a_i-1)(a_i^2+a_i+1)=0$ and since $a_i\neq 1$ this means $a_i^2+a_i+1=0$

Summing these we get $\sum a_i^2+\sum a_i+n=0=2\sum a_i+n=3\sum a_i+\left(n-\sum a_i\right)$

You should be able to conclude from there.